# How to compress folders in .tar.gz with least RAM in java?

Tags: java, directory, zip, tar, ram

I need to compress folders in a .tar.gz file. For that I had used the apache-commons library in Java. But now my folders are getting bigger, and each time I try to compress them, it uses a big amount of RAM (more than 4Gb).

I run that on a virtual mahine with Debian 10 , and 8 Gb of RAM.

I'm using this [code](https://memorynotfound.com/java-tar-example-compress-decompress-tar-tar-gz-files/)

I tried to do the same thing with the tar command in the terminal but it's as greedy ad the java program.

So I'm looking for a better solution.
I also tried to compress folders with the  java.util package but it wasn't successful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think I haven't enough  enough memory (only 50Gb) to have a correct swap space

Comment: Edit your question and include your code directly in your question as text.  A link to another site will eventually go stale, which would make your question useless to future readers.  (My guess is that you’re reading files entirely into memory, instead of reading one byte or a few bytes at a time, or using [Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,java.io.OutputStream%29).)